# fatal error call to a member function prepare() on boolean in functions.php online 32

Tags: php, mysql, funciones, poo

Estoy haciendo un sistema de noticias anda perfecto en apache y en un servidor on line. Este error surge al hacer funcionar el sitio en un servidor local de windows iis puede ser las versiones de php? tiene la 5.6

```
$bd_config = array(

        'basedatos' => 'noticias',
        'usuario' => 'root',
        'pass' => '****'

         );


$noticias_config = array(

        'post_por_pagina' => '3',
        'carpeta_imagenes' => 'img/'

         );
```

LINEA 32 -------------------------------------- function.php

```
function obtener_post($post_por_pagina, $conexion) {

    $inicio = (pagina_actual() > 1) ? pagina_actual() * $post_por_pagina - $post_por_pagina: 0;
    $sentencia = $conexion->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM articulos LIMIT $inicio, $post_por_pagina"); 
    $sentencia->execute();
    return $sentencia->fetchAll();

}
```

Comment: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando la conexión falla, recibes como respuesta un `false`, luego tu conexión no es un objeto PDO o MySQLi, sino un booleano.

Tienes que verificar el valor del objeto $conexión.

```
<?php
$conexión = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "mi_bd");

if (!$conexión) {
    echo "Error: No se pudo conectar a MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "errno de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "error de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
```

(ejemplo tomado de [mysqli-connect](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php))

Comment: function conexion($bd_config){

try{
 $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$bd_config['basedatos'], $bd_config['usuario'], $bd_config['pass']);
 return $conexion;
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
  return false;
 }

}

Comment: La conexión fallida no arroja una excepción, por lo tanto el try catch no detecta ningún problema.

Comment: Te agradezco tus rápidas respuestas estoy comenzando con php mirando tutoriales y haciendo cursos. Mi duda es también porque cuando lo pase a unservidor iis me tira ese error el codigo esta tal cual de como esta en los servidores que funcioana perfecto  decis que el error puede estar en el user pass o la base?

Comment: Si es el mismo PHP no tiene relación con el IIS. Si en cambio pasaste de un PHP en linux a un PHP en windows (por ejemplo WAMP), tienes que verificar que la extensión mysqli esté habilitada